# how to store sql select query output into excel csv. before manually converting excel choosing text format in csv to store and data in visible format

Tags: excel, database, postgresql, csv

i have tried run below query

set output file to get query output in file
`postgres=# \o /home/linuxconfig/output.csv`

run query to store in file
`postgres=# select * from dummy_table;`

exit from postgres
`postgres=# \q`

basically it gives me the output in structure format. my table has uniquery primary transaction ids. so when i run the query it gives me the output in csv but it give me with extra zeros and i also tried to use txt. but i need better way to save query output and manage records in good excel format..with not extra zeros and letters.

all these steps i have added in shell script and  scheduled in crontab but dose not worked for me. so started usng pgadmin4 and manually run query copy the data from pgadmin into csv. to save proper data in csv. befor this i was converting that excel by clicking on excel format cell option. and choosing "text" to save sql output in proper way. with dose not includes extra zeros and number.

i am looking for solution script is there any way to do this all in shell script or pgadmin or postgres. any idea. please suggest. currently i am using postgres.v.13 latest version. should i have to use other softwares..

Comment: CSV is just a text file with delimiters, not an Excel file. There are libraries that can create real Excel (xlsx) file sin any language,  eg Epplus in C#, openpyxl in Python and more.

Comment: can we do this in shell script....!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you really running Postgres 9.2? If not what version?
2. Look at `\copy` in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).
3. Also if you using Postgres 12+ then at `psql` link look at `pset format csv` for use with `\o`

**UPDATE**.

Example for 3):

```
test(5432)=# select * from animals;
 id  | cond  | animal 
-----+-------+--------
   1 | fair  | crow
 200 | fair  | crow
  16 | fair  | heron
 101 | great | gopher
(4 rows)

test(5432)=# \pset format csv
Output format is csv.

test(5432)=# \o animals.csv

test(5432)=# select * from animals;

test(5432)=# \o

cat animals.csv 
id,cond,animal
1,fair,crow
200,fair,crow
16,fair,heron
101,great,gopher
```

Comment: could you please provide me more link how to use these with latest postgres13 for 3rd point.